# Big request size of 1.5 MB with multiple levels kind of tree form is making browser unresponsive yield call

Tags: reactjs, graphql, redux-saga

// This data is huge close to 1.5 MB multiple levels with nesting

```
let result = yield call('API call',action.copyData)
if(result.data.mergedData)
{
  yield put(setCopyData(result.data.mergedData)); 
}
```

its a kind of parent child data with levels , if levels and data is less this call works perfectly.

after making this call , not getting any response in Network tab as browser becomes unresponsive after few minutes of this call.

Should I compress this json request or what should be the way as I cannot break this request into page format due to nature of data as it should be updated in one go and logically binded.
is there any maximum size of request which browser can handle

Comment: It might be ok for the browser, and in a production build of the react app. But if you are using redux devtools or other development tools and addons, they might cause the freeze.

Comment: If the problem is redux-devtools, there's a troubleshooting guide here: https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension/blob/master/docs/Troubleshooting.md#excessive-use-of-memory-and-cpu

Comment: its a production build, this API is kind of a gateway and its call is graphQL

Comment: Yeah. Then it's not devtools. But there is a different bottleneck somewhere. 1.5Mb should not be too much data to handle for a web app using redux/react/graphql. But finding the specific bottleneck in your app might be outside of the scope of stackoverflow.

Comment: unable to figure out yet, this data is kind of tree view with multiple levels , is there any issue with multiple levels in request with graphQL or saga ?

Comment: Not in itself. Unless you do a lot of calculations in the reducer after dispatching `setCopyData`. You say that it's not possible to break the request into page format, but maybe there's some other way to use a smaller data payload, to figure out where the breaking point in your app is. And monitor the cpu and ram usage of the browser. If the network tab is nonresponsive, that might be caused by a memory leak or excessive recursion.

Comment: Are you using any immutablity libraries or redux middleware other than addition to redux-saga?

Comment: yes using redux for state management